# Cannot construct from a reference in a generic function (value does not live long enough)

Tags: generics, rust, lifetime, borrow-checker

I have a method that takes some parameters, creates (decrypts) an intermediate value from them and tries to construct a type instance from that intermediate value. This works fine as long as the type is fixed. If I want to support multiple types via generics I run into trouble. Here is minified code:

```
impl Factory
{
    pub fn get<'a, T>(&'a self, value: &'a str) -> T
        where T: From<&'a str>
    {
        let value_parsed = value.chars().rev().collect::<String>();
        return T::from(&value_parsed);
    }
}
```

You can run the full code [here](https://www.onlinegdb.com/3jZC15551). Compiling produces the following error:

```
31 |     pub fn get<'a, T>(&'a self, value: &'a str) -> T
   |                -- lifetime `'a` defined here
...
35 |         return T::from(&value_parsed);
   |                --------^^^^^^^^^^^^^-
   |                |       |
   |                |       borrowed value does not live long enough
   |                argument requires that `value_parsed` is borrowed for `'a`
36 |     }
   |     - `value_parsed` dropped here while still borrowed
```

As I said, using `Item` in the method signature rather than a generic type gets rid of this error. Not passing a reference to `T::from()` but rather moving the temporary value is also an option but that makes little sense given that `value_parsed` isn’t actually being consumed here, it gets awkward and inconsistent with the rest of my codebase.

Any way I can make sure `value_parsed` lives long enough? Or is there some other solution short of not using references here?

Comment: Moving the value *is* the appropriate option there. It has to be converted to an owned value at some point; you can't just return a reference to something that was created inside your function, because it will be immediately dropped.

Comment: I’m not returning a reference. I’m constructing a new type from the reference, one that doesn’t hold onto the reference beyond construction.

Comment: The problem is that the compiler doesn't know that. `From` technically *could* just create an object that holds onto the reference you gave it.

Comment: @Herohtar: Yes, I already figured that out – using a custom trait I can work around this problem. So I answered my own question, but I’m not sure whether this is the best way to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would use a [higher-rank trait bound](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nomicon/hrtb.html) to indicate that the type `T` can be made from a value with *any* lifetime, as opposed to a *specific* lifetime when used as generics on the function:

```
pub fn get<T>(&self, value: &str) -> T
    where T: for<'a> From<&'a str>
          // ^^^^^^^
```

What you had before was indicating that `T` could be built from a reference with the lifetime based on `self` and `value`, however, since `value_parsed` is a local variable, a reference to it cannot satisfy that lifetime constraint.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out using my own trait works here, one that doesn’t require me to specify a reference to the type in the signature – and consequently doesn’t require associating a lifetime with the trait:

```
trait Get<T>
{
    fn get(value: &T) -> Self;
}
```

Using this trait the method can compile:

```
pub fn get<'a, T>(&'a self, value: &'a str) -> T
    where T: Get<String>
{
    let value_parsed = value.chars().rev().collect::<String>();
    return T::get(&value_parsed);
}
```

I’m not sure whether this is the best solution, but this solution works.